# Train Captcha OCR Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, ocr, captcha

How can I train an AI model to read CAPTCHA images and convert them to text using Python?

I have a dataset like this:

```
dataset
├── FmTK.png
├── LKEsf.png
├── IDJsgf.png
├── Kbgh.png
├── sgKSh.png
├── oKDKgf.png
├── ...
```

Where the image name corresponds to the text inside it.

Here is an example of CAPTCHA images:

[image: captcha]
[image: captcha]
[image: captcha]
[image: captcha]

I've tried this code:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

data_dir = Path("dataset/")

images = sorted(list(map(str, list(data_dir.glob("*.png")))))
labels = [img.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split(".png")[0] for img in images]
characters = set(char for label in labels for char in label)
characters = sorted(list(characters))

print("Number of images found: ", len(images))
print("Number of labels found: ", len(labels))
print("Number of unique characters: ", len(characters))
print("Characters present: ", characters)

batch_size = 16

img_width = 200
img_height = 50

downsample_factor = 4

max_length = max([len(label) for label in labels])

char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None
)

num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)


def split_data(images, labels, train_size=0.9, shuffle=True):
    size = len(images)
    indices = np.arange(size)
    if shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    train_samples = int(size * train_size)
    x_train, y_train = images[indices[:train_samples]], labels[indices[:train_samples]]
    x_valid, y_valid = images[indices[train_samples:]], labels[indices[train_samples:]]
    return x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = split_data(np.array(images), np.array(labels))

def encode_single_sample(img_path, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=1)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
    img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    label = char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))
    return {"image": img, "label": label}

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))
validation_dataset = (
    validation_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

_, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(10, 5))
for batch in train_dataset.take(1):
    images = batch["image"]
    labels = batch["label"]
    for i in range(16):
        img = (images[i] * 255).numpy().astype("uint8")
        label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(labels[i])).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].imshow(img[:, :, 0].T, cmap="gray")
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].set_title(label)
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].axis("off")
plt.show()

class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")
        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return y_pred


def build_model():
    input_img = layers.Input(
        shape=(img_width, img_height, 1), name="image", dtype="float32"
    )
    labels = layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,), dtype="float32")
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv1",
    )(input_img)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv2",
    )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool2")(x)
    new_shape = ((img_width // 4), (img_height // 4) * 64)
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name="reshape")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense1")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    x = layers.Dense(
        len(char_to_num.get_vocabulary()) + 1, activation="softmax", name="dense2"
    )(x)
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
    )
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()

epochs = 100
early_stopping_patience = 10
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=early_stopping_patience, restore_best_weights=True
)

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
)

prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
prediction_model.summary()

def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][
        :, :max_length
    ]
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text

for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
    batch_images = batch["image"]
    batch_labels = batch["label"]
    preds = prediction_model.predict(batch_images)
    pred_texts = decode_batch_predictions(preds)
    orig_texts = []
    for label in batch_labels:
        label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(label)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        orig_texts.append(label)
    _, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(15, 5))
    for i in range(len(pred_texts)):
        img = (batch_images[i, :, :, 0] * 255).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
        img = img.T
        title = f"Prediction: {pred_texts[i]}"
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].imshow(img, cmap="gray")
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].set_title(title)
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].axis("off")
plt.show()
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\python\captcha> python -u "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\train.py"
Number of images found:  50
Number of labels found:  50
Number of unique characters:  43
Characters present:  ['0', '1', '2', '4', '6', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 
'f', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 's', 'u', 'x', 'z']
2023-11-19 23:50:33.869524: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\python\captcha\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 80, in <module>
    for batch in train_dataset.take(1):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 809, in __next__
    return self._next_internal()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 772, in _next_internal
    ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3055, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5888, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [5], [batch]: [6] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

The issue is not with a small number of images; I have tested with a large number, but it still fails, showing the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.